How can I have only 1 record for a case statement by group?
How can I have a single record for case statement by grouping? If there is an other solution, please let me know.
Here is an example of 2 records but I only want one. You will see the only difference is the last 2 columns which are either F or T. If it is Late_Process, I want a T and if it is also Miss_Cutoff, I want a T in the same record instead of 2.

SEL
    SPDM.PRODUCT
    ,SPDM.OCNTR
    ,SPDM.DCNTR
    ,SPDM.MLTYP
    ,SQ.RETURN_FLG
    ,SPDM.ODT
    ,SQ.F_PLT_F_PROC_WC ORIGINATING_WC
    ,SQ.F_PLT_F_PROC_DTM_LOC
    ,SCANS.RELATED_SCAN_WC DESTINATION_WC
    ,SCANS.RELATED_SCAN_DTM_LOC
    ,SPDM.ECUST CUSTOMER_ID
    ,SPDM.ITEM
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SCANS.PAT_CAT_SEQ = 500
            AND CHECK_RESULT_CODE = 'OT'
        THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'
     END LATE_PROCESS
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SCANS.PAT_CAT_SEQ = 600
            AND CHECK_RESULT_CODE = 'OT'
        THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'
     END MISS_CUTOFF
FROM DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_SPDM_FLASH SPDM
LEFT JOIN DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_PAT_FLASH_SCAN SCANS
ON SPDM.ITEM = SCANS.PIN
    AND SPDM.FYFW = SCANS.FYFW
    AND SCANS.PAT_CAT_SEQ IN (500, 600)
    AND SCANS.DP0_IND = 1
INNER JOIN PIN_ORIGINATING_OT OOT
ON SPDM.ITEM = OOT.PIN
LEFT JOIN DL_SQ_PRD_INT.VW_FCT_ITEM SQ
ON SCANS.ITEM_ID = SQ.ITEM_ID
WHERE SPDM.ITEM = '2010778075710766'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14;


So to clarify, you want sort of a "summed" (in lack of a better word) result, that is, if you have T on multiple rows (either on the process or on the COT), to have T on a single row, showing both being a late process and a missed COT as true right? What RDBMS is it? This might require some magic that is specific to each type of database.

Yes correct. Since LateProcess and MissCutoff can be either T or F. If It is T, we know it is not F so instead of having a second record with the reverse, we can have only 1 with T in both columns. I am using Teradata. Would it be simpler if I break the DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_PAT_FLASH_SCAN SCANS into 2, 1 filter with 500 and the other filter with 600 and Left join them?

Are there events other than a late process or missed COT? Or only those 2?

In my filter of DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_PAT_FLASH_SCAN SCANS, there is (500,600) it is a left join 1-to-many(2). I think that is why I have 2 records.

I saw that. But I don't mean in this line, I mean in general. Do you search for any other types of events? or only 500+600?

It would be only for those 2 events because we have the data for only those 2 but if we had 5 events, would it be 5 columns? For example 100,200,300,400,500..

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. and Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question both apply here.

Alright, I answered with a POC slightly adapted from Oracle, unfortunately, so you'll have to adjusy if for Teradata (sorry, but I can't really test your use-case online and I don't have Teradata). Check if it works for you. If it's what you need, I also wrote about the case where you search for 5 events (sometime in the future in case you'll need it and if the app adds them).

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample table data and expected result as properly formatted text (no images, no links.)

And also add a tag for the dbms you're using. (The above query is product specific.)

Note that case is an expression, not statement. And tables have rows, not records.

As you probably guessed, checking for 5 events would return 5 rows.
You are close, but what you need to do is LEFT JOIN multiple times, once for each event (in your case twice, but in our example from the comments, 5 times), with its own condition, but limit the event.
Minor disclaimer, I don't use Teradata, my first love was and always will be Oracle, so try to adapt it, but I think you'll get the idea.
SEL
    SPDM.PRODUCT
    ,SPDM.OCNTR
    ,SPDM.DCNTR
    ,SPDM.MLTYP
    ,SQ.RETURN_FLG
    ,SPDM.ODT
    ,SQ.F_PLT_F_PROC_WC ORIGINATING_WC
    ,SQ.F_PLT_F_PROC_DTM_LOC
    ,SCANS.RELATED_SCAN_WC DESTINATION_WC
    ,SCANS.RELATED_SCAN_DTM_LOC
    ,SPDM.ECUST CUSTOMER_ID
    ,SPDM.ITEM
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SCANS_LP.PAT_CAT_SEQ = 500
            AND CHECK_RESULT_CODE = 'OT'
        THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'
     END LATE_PROCESS
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SCANS_COT.PAT_CAT_SEQ = 600
            AND CHECK_RESULT_CODE = 'OT'
        THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'
     END MISS_CUTOFF
FROM DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_SPDM_FLASH SPDM,
(SELECT * FROM 
DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_PAT_FLASH_SCAN SCANS
WHERE SCANS.PAT_CAT_SEQ = 500
AND SCANS.DP0_IND = 1) SCANS_LP,
(SELECT * FROM 
DL_SQ_PRD_INT.FCT_PAT_FLASH_SCAN SCANS
WHERE SCANS.PAT_CAT_SEQ = 600
AND SCANS.DP0_IND = 1) SCANS_COT
LEFT JOIN ON SPDM.ITEM = SCANS_LP.PIN
    AND SPDM.FYFW = SCANS_LP.FYFW
LEFT JOIN ON SPDM.ITEM = SCANS_COT.PIN
    AND SPDM.FYFW = SCANS_COT.FYFW
INNER JOIN PIN_ORIGINATING_OT OOT
ON SPDM.ITEM = OOT.PIN
LEFT JOIN DL_SQ_PRD_INT.VW_FCT_ITEM SQ
ON SCANS_LP.ITEM_ID = SQ.ITEM_ID
ON SCANS_COT.ITEM_ID = SQ.ITEM_ID
WHERE SPDM.ITEM = '2010778075710766'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14;

Sorry for the Oracle-Teradata spaghetti, but I don't think I can do much of an MRE online without some DML and DDL from you. But the idea is simple: use the scans table each time for a dedicated event. So for example, if 600 doesn't exist for a reference, it should be F. If it doesn't return, you could COALESCE in your CASE for empty results with F as databases do have issues joining "on empty" in some cases.
